# Rails 4: Referral Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am creating a `referral` model that will be able to link 2 clients, one that was referred and one that did the referring.  I already have the `client` model, but am wondering the correct way to setup the `referral` model such that I can query:

```
Client.find(x).referrals
# returns all referrals where referrer has the client's id

Client.find(x).referred_by
# returns client that referred this client
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a join table http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table

Comment: Seems you're trying to do a many-to-many associations, with Referrals as the join table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up two associations to the same table is one of the trickiest associations in ActiveRecord. The key is to setup different associations for each foreign key column.

So lets start with the join table:

```
# This is a Rails 5 migration - don't copy paste it
# You'll have to generate one for rails 4
class CreateReferrals < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :referrals do |t|
      t.belongs_to :referrer_id, foreign_key: false
      t.belongs_to :referred_id, foreign_key: false
      # Since the table for the foreign key cannot be automatically derived you need to add them manually
      add_foreign_key :referrals, :clients, column: :referrer_id
      add_foreign_key :referrals, :clients, column: :referred_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Lets setup the associations on Referral:

```
class Referral < < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :referrer, class_name: 'Client'
  belongs_to :referred, class_name: 'Client'
end
```

Nothing to funky here yet. `class_name: 'Client'` tells ActiveRecord (AR) which table the association points to since it cannot be derived from the name of the assocation.  Now lets create the inverse associations on Client:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals, class_name: 'Referral', 
    foreign_key: 'referrer_id'
  has_many :referrals_as_referred, class_name: 'Referral', 
    foreign_key: 'referred_id'
end
```

To add the associations to other clients that are referred or referrers to a client use an indirect assocation:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # clients reffered by this client
  has_many :referred_clients, 
        through: :referrals,
        source: :referred
  has_many :referrers, 
        through: :referrals_as_referred,
        source: :referrer
end
```

- `through: :referrals` tells AR to join through the assocation named `:referrals`.
- `source: :referred` indicates the assocation on the join table to use.

Comment: Really appreciate the thorough response.  This was much trickier than I expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use self association for this. On Client model, add referrals_id column. The association in Client model would be like this :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals, class_name: "Client", foreign_key: :referrals_id
  belongs_to :referred_by, class_name: "Client", foreign_key: :referrals_id
end
```

Consider you have these two records in tables.

```
[{  
   "id":1,
   "name":"Admin",
   "referrals_id": nil,
 },
 {  
   "id":2,
   "name":"Client",
   "referrals_id":1,
 }]
```

Now you can query for referrals will returns all referrals where referrer has the client's id

```
Client.find(1).referrals
```

This will generate a SQL like :

```
`SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."referrals_id" = ?  [["referrals_id", 1]]`
```

for referred_by will returns client that referred this client

```
Client.find(2).referred_by
```

This will generate SQL like:

```
SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: For this solution to work, the referrals_id column needs not to be null when you create a new user. For me this was a show stopper.